# HP 2000 Notebook PC freezes

Tags: ati, freeze, hp, 32-bit, 13.04

I'm not sure the of the model name, nor if that would help, but I believe it is this: [Hp 2000 Notebook PC 2000-2b09wm](http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-Refurbished-Winter-Blue-15.6-2000-2b09wm-Laptop-PC-with-AMD-E-300-Accelerated-Processor-and-Windows-8-Operating-System/23081581).  
For some reason it likes to freeze randomly. I tried using the proprietary graphics driver, but that didn't help, except for make the experience unbearable. I am using Ubuntu 13.04, as any earlier versions are worse, and this version can handle all my hardware perfectly (It's also extraordinarily stable).

The overall specs:

- AMD E-300 1.3Ghz Dual Core APU
- 4GB RAM
- 64-bit system, 32-bit OS (This isn't the problem, or at least, not the only problem, as 64-bit works just as bad.)

This computer came with UEFI boot, but I disabled it in the BIOS Settings, and continued to change the hard drive from GPT to MS-DOS

I'm kind of a newbie, so please, if there is anything else you would like to know ask away.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Comment: If the question is "how do I stop the freezes", then I'm afraid it's off-topic, because this is clearly a bug. You can report the bug to the developers if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The first things to analyze the problem is to look into the logfiles of the system. If you go to a terminal and enter `dmesg`, you will get the messages of the running session.

In the terminal look at the log files in the folder

```
ls /var/log
```

where probably `syslog` will be most interesting for you. Try to figure out if there are messages just before the freeze - easily identified by the fact that any new session begins counting by 0 again. When you find some hint, post the corresponding lines and maybe someone can help.

The commands you want to use for reading the files are e.g.

```
tail -n 250 /var/log/syslog
```

which returns the last 250 lines of syslog. Ore you can go through the files line by line with

```
less /var/log/syslog
```